# Bulk Insert dictionaries to sqlite3 db using python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, dictionary, bulkinsert

I have list of dictionaries and I am trying to save it in the sqlite3 db. I know how can i do it using cursor.execute() (shown below) but I am facing problem while I am trying to do bulk insert using executemany().

```
 list1 =  [{'time': "20190521", 'id': '1', 'a': 0.001, 'b': 0.001,'c': 0.001, 'd': 0.001},
    {'time': "20190522", 'id': '2', 'm': 0.001, "n":0.001, 'o': 0.001, 'p': 0.001}]
import sqlite3
def create_table(conn, create_table_sql):
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute(create_table_sql)


db_filename = 'test.db'
db_is_new = not os.path.exists(db_filename)

conn = Util.create_connection(db_filename)
cur = conn.cursor()

current = "CREATE TABLE list1_table (id TEXT, time TEXT , " \
                   "fname TEXT , value INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(id, time, name))"
create_table(conn, current)
cur.execute("CREATE index name_id on current_features(name)")
```

**My Solution:**

**Using executemany()**: Not getting expected result.

```
for i in range(0, len(list1)):
    dicts = features_current_list[i]
    id = dicts['id']
    time = dicts['time']
    query = "INSERT into list1_table (id, time, name, value) values (?,?,?,?);"
    cur.executemany(query, zip(dicts.keys(), dicts.values()))
    # print(*zip(dicts.keys(), dicts.values()))
```

**Result:**

```
(None, None, 'time', '20190521')
(None, None, 'id', '1')
(None, None, 'a', 0.001)
(None, None, 'b', 0.584)
(None, None, 'c', 0.001)
(None, None, 'd', 0.001)
(None, None, 'time', '20190522')
(None, None, 'id', '2')
(None, None, 'm', 0.01)
(None, None, 'n', 0.01)
(None, None, 'o', 0.001)
(None, None, 'p', 0.09)
```

**Using execute()**: It works fine when I am trying to do it using execute()

```
for i in range(0, len(list1)):
    dicts = features_current_list[i]
    id = dicts['id']
    time = dicts['time']
    for k, v in dicts.items():
        if k not in ["id", "time"]:
            cur.execute("INSERT into previous_features (id, time, name, value) values (?,?,?,?);", (id, time, k, v))
```

**Expected Result**

```
id  time      name value
1  20190521   a     0.001
1  20190521   b     0.001
1  20190521   c     0.001
1  20190521   d     0.001
2  20190522   m     0.001
2  20190522   n     0.001
2  20190522   o     0.001
2  20190522   p     0.001
```

Comment: What is the result when you try the `executemany()`?

Comment: @glibdud, updated question.

Comment: @glibdud, how we can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Sqlite cursors don't permit named parameters, so giving the executemany() a dictionary confuses it.
Just pass it a list of tuples and it'll be fine.